# Seeking Playwright Version to Browser Version Compatibility Table for Automated Binary Deployment

Tags: playwright

We're using Playwright and due to security restrictions, we have to manually download and deploy the browser binaries in our on-premise infrastructure.

We're interested in finding a table or documentation detailing the compatibility between Playwright versions and browser versions.

For instance, the [GitHub release page for the Java version of Playwright for v1.38.0](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-java/releases/tag/v1.38.0) mentions these browser versions:

- Chromium 117.0.5938.62
- Mozilla Firefox 117.0
- WebKit 17.0

When utilizing Playwright v1.38.0, the necessary browser binaries are sourced from the Microsoft CDN. Notably, the Chromium version compatible with Playwright v1.38.0 is Chromium 117.0.5938.62. This correlates with the Chromium build number 1080, which appears in the CDN URL:

```
Downloading Chromium 117.0.5938.62 (playwright build v1080) from https://playwright.azureedge.net/builds/chromium/1080/chromium-mac-arm64.zip
```

If there's a table detailing this relationship, it would greatly streamline our process for automated downloading and on-premise deployment of the browser binaries.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Best regards,
Patrick

Comment: npx playwright install --dry-run should help you for that. This will give you download URLs per version. We don't have a exact table online, but should be easily buildable as a small script using e.g. https://unpkg.com/browse/playwright-core@1.38.1/browsers.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That table is currently available [here](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/main/packages/playwright-core/browsers.json). Obviously, you will be able to git checkout specific release tags for the version of the library you are working with.